# Using SQL Server, nodejs and bycrypt, request ends before function is recieved

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to nodejs and have stumbled into a problem with my code.

The documentation for SQL Server and a guide I found on Youtube both handle their code this way, but after starting to use bycrypt I've noticed my function ends after the request is complete although I'm using `.then()`.

Anyways, here's my code so far:

```
router.post('/login',  (req, res) => {
    getLoginDetails(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    })
});

async function getLoginDetails(username, password) {
    await pool1Connect;
    try {
        const request = pool1.request();
        request.input('username', sql.NVarChar, username);
    
        request.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username', (err, result) => {        
            if (err) {
                return ({err: err})
            }
            if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, result.recordset[0].user_password, (err, response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        console.log(result.recordset);
                        return(result.recordset);
                    } else {
                        return({message: "Wrong password or username!"})
                    }
                })
                return(result)
            } else {
                return({message: "user not found!"})
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

I tried logging both the request and the return value from the function `getLoginDetails` and the request log came faster, so I assume it's not waiting for the program to actually finish and I can't figure out why...

Sorry if that's obvious, but I'd love to get some help here!

EDIT:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    // res.send(getLoginDetails(req.body.username, req.body.password))
    await pool1Connect
    try {
        const request = pool1.request();
        request.input('username', sql.NVarChar, req.body.username);
        request.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username', (err, result) => {
            console.log(result);
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, result.recordset[0].user_password, (err, response) => {
                if (response) {
                    res.send(result);
                } else {
                    res.send('wrong password')
                }
                
            })
            //res.send(result)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

This code works, but when I tried to encapsulate it in a function it still didn't work.

@Anatoly mentioned `.query` not finishing in time which makes sense, but I thought mssql `.query` is an async function?

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Comment: When you refer to my language, you mean grammar wise?

Comment: I mean profanity

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, that's embarrassing!
That was a change I did 3 hours gpomg into this problem and did not remember that  before i posted here,I was furstrated and obviously did not expect anyone to see it, that won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises from an wrong assumption that callbacks and promises are alike, but on the contrary callbacks don't "respect" promise/async constructs

When the program hits the bottom of `getLoginDetails` the progrm execution has already split into 2 branches one branch returned you the (empty) result whereas the other one still busy with crypto operations.

Though it is true that an async function always returns a promise but that doesn't cover any future callbacks that might execute inside it. As soon as node reaches the end of function or any return statement the async function's promise get resolved(therefore future callbacks are meaningless), what you can do instead is handroll your own promise which encampasses the callbacks as well

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

        getLoginDetails(req.body.username, req.body.password))
            .then((result)=>{
                res.send(result);
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                res.send(err);
            })

});

async function getLoginDetails(username, password) {
    await pool1Connect

    return new Promise( (resolve,reject)  => {

        try {
            const request = pool1.request();
            request.input('username', sql.NVarChar, username);
            request.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username', (err, result) => {
                console.log(result);
                bcrypt.compare(password, result.recordset[0].user_password, (err, response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        resolve('wrong password')
                    }

                })

            })
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation!
I did assume callbacks worked like promises, thanks for clarifying.
Marked as answer,

Comment: Thanks, just noticed I forgot to declare '/login' handler function as `async` hope you caught it. In case you don't want async-await in your routes just use chained`then`ing instead

Comment: Decided to take a break after 3 hours of trying to solve it, but i did just fix the problem by creating the function inside the login and not on a seperate one.

How would I take the code from my edit and transform it into a separate function? create a promise like you did?

Also, is that even good practice to change the /login handler function to async? I cant think of a reason its bad but I also didnt see many people doing that

Comment: Code updated, as of async await there is no problem but sometimes it is better to avoid if you can

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return any result to `getLoginDetails`. Either you use `async` versions of `request.query` and `bcrypt.compare` (if any) or wrap `request.query` to `new Promise((resolve, reject)` like this:

```
const asyncResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   request.query('SELECT ...
     ...
     if (err) {
        resolve({err: err}) // replace all return statements with resolve calls
     }
     ...
})
const queryResult = await asyncResult;
```

Comment: I dont get it though, bcrypt,compare() is supposedly an async method and .query() is also one, because whenever I tried to put an 'await' it told me it isnt needed (which made me assume it was also an async method)

I managed to somewhat resolve it by changing the .post request to an async one and handling all the code from there (removing getLoginDetails), but i still would rather to use a seperate method for that as its going to be needed in multiple places...

isnt .query an async method?

Comment: Quite the opposite: if you are told `await` is not need that means it's not an async method.

Comment: Yes, I understand it now.
Thanks!